# java how to connect to a MySQL database in OpenShift

Tags: java, mysql, openshift

```
package library;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class conexion {

    private String server = "jdbc:mysql://" + System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST") + ":" + System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT") + "/" + System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME") + "";
    private String user = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME");
    private String pass = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD");
    private Connection conn;

    public Connection conectar() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(server, user, pass);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return this.conn;
    }

}
```

I have a java application lodged in OpenShift but when I try to connect it to the cartridge mysql nothing happens when you connect. only it stays in the servlet and takes no other action

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what type of java server you are running on OpenShift, try reading through one of these articles, which should help you get your database connection up and running:

- Tomcat: https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-ds.html
- JBoss AS: https://developers.openshift.com/en/jbossas-ds.html
- JBoss EAP: https://developers.openshift.com/en/jbosseap-ds.html
- WildFly: https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-ds.html